# Design of accepted answer toggle

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

In conjunction with the elementary OS defaults, which are very light atop white backgrounds, many of the website elements on this Stack exchange kind of get lost. For example, the horizontal rule is nearly invisible, and I think the "accepted answer" toggle could be more visually attracting to the eyes of question owners. Our community is going to skew towards new users asking troubleshooting questions, so we need more visual tricks to pull them towards the interactions we need for our community. Otherwise the tech support is even more thankless when we put hours into a response only to get zero upvotes and no accepted answer check.

Comment: For some reason (I know not why) the elementary Stack Exchange has a far lower *answered* ratio than other sites. I've given 16 fairly thorough answers, of which only three were accepted (one of which was an answer to my own question). This wouldn't be as frustrating if it weren't for the fact so much functionality of Stack Exchange is based around reputation points.

Comment: StackExchange will not yet allow us to customise our appearance ourselves. This typically, but not always, takes place after leaving beta and holding an ellection.

Answer (score 5):

We don't have any access to the stylesheet. This is what we get during the Beta.